# Can QGIS label buffers have a different vertical size than the horizontal size?

Tags: qgis-3, labeling, buffer

I am producing a map which includes a narrow street with parallel boundaries.  Down the centre of the street midway between the street boundaries and parallel to them is a line layer which is a continuous tram line.

The street also has a name label which needs to be displayed midway between the street boundaries, and therefore it overlies the tram line in places.

For clarity I can set a horizontal buffer size to 2.0 for the street name label so that there is a suitable gap between each end of it and the underlying tram line.

However, this buffer size (2.0) is such that its vertical size covers part of the adjacent street boundaries.  If the vertical buffer could be set to 1.0 while the horizontal remained at 2.0, the street boundaries would not be overwritten.  Is there a way of achieving this outcome?

Comment: Have a look at label mask feature, it will let you  choose witch layer to hide

Comment: Link to label mask doc : https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/style_library/label_settings.html#mask-tab

Comment: Thanks, J.R., but I can't see how a mask or buffer can have differing vertical and horizontal components.  There is just the one size input box on both screens, and I need a "length" and "height" which are not the same value.

Comment: With mask you could choose to hide the tram line layer but not the street layer so you won't need different length and height size

Comment: But I don't want to hide anything.  I need both the tramline symbol and the street name text to appear on the map.  Or am I missing something in your comment?

Comment: After some experimation, I think I might have solved the problem by using Background instead of Mask.  Background accepts X and Y values, and by tweaking these I seem to have achieved my goal.  I haven't posted it as an answer yet as I'd like to know if any more knowledgeable QGIS users have comments on whether this is a valid solution.